# How to prevent access to admin port when click backspace navigation on browser

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I trust you are keeping safe.

Please I need your help. I created login and logout method is user controller which are working fine. When I logout and redirected to login page as expect. I discover that as I click on backward arrow on the browser, I have access to the admin portal with login.

Explanation with code implemented

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('UserModel');
        $data = array();
    }

    
    public function login(){
        $this->load->view('login/login');
    }
    

    public function loginForm(){
        $data = array();
        $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
        $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
        $check = $this->UserModel->checkUser($data);
        if($check){
            $sdata = array();
            $sdata['id '] = $check->id;
            $sdata['userlogin'] = TRUE;
            $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
            redirect('AdminController');

        }else{
            $sdata = array();
            $sdata['msg'] = '<span style="color:red">User name and or password is incorrect</span>';
            $this->session->set_flashdata($sdata);
            redirect("UserController/login");
        }
    }
    
    public function logout(){
        $this->session->unset_userdata($id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userlogin', FALSE);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect("UserController/login");
    }
}
```

As I refresh my URL, the login page works fine

I logged-in and redirected to Admin portal which work as expected

I logout and redirected to login page which is also working fine as expected

Now, when I click the "Click to go back" arrow on the browser, I am redirected to admin portal without login

I want to prevent this behavior. Click to go back should also request for login

See my admin controller code below

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AdminController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    
    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('admin/admin_page');
        
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Note: I am using codeIgniter 3.11

Comment: check in your admin controller for valid session, if not redirect to login

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I add the following function to my admin panel to prevent go back access

```
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if (!$this->session->userdata('login_id'))
             return redirect("LoginController");
    }
```